# AHK Gui Add Edit's variable cannot be accessed

Tags: variables, autohotkey

I have an issue I can't solve regarding AHK. My code:

```
begin()

begin() {
    Global Input
    Gui, Add, Edit, vInput gInputChanged
}

InputChanged() {
    MsgBox, Your input is %Input%
}
```

Simple enough, eh? However when `InputChanged()` is triggered the variable `Input` is never correct (it is always null).

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Function Variables and Scope](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#Locals)

Example:

```
Input := "Hello" ; Our Variable Defined outside of our Function

begin() ; Call the function passing no Variables

begin() {
    Global Input
    MsgBox, Global! Input = %Input%
    InputChangedLocally(Input) ; Pass the Input variable which is 'Hello'

}

InputChangedLocally(Input) {
    Input .= " World!" ; Change Local variable
    MsgBox, Changed Locally %Input%
    OnlyGlobalInput()
}

OnlyGlobalInput() {
    Global Input

     ; Notice it is not 'Hello World!' even though we changed it above!

    MsgBox, Global! Input = %Input%
    InputNotPassedOrGlobal()
}

InputNotPassedOrGlobal() {
    MsgBox, Your input is %Input% ; Blank as we never accessed any thing!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

got the same problem, not figure out why this happen yet, but can use this workround

```
    ControlGetText, TestCode2, Edit1,A
```

to get the input value